# Setting Selected Option With GeoPlugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, html-select

I am using the http://geoplugin.net plugin to detect the users location. I have a `<select>` with a list of states, and using the jQuery

```
$.getJSON(url, function(data){
    var state = data['geoplugin_region'];
    $('#states').val(state).attr('selected',true);
    var selectId = "#" + state ;
    var citySelect = selectId + "-cities";
    $(citySelect).show();
});
```

Then it uses another plugin I wrote to display the correct select that has the cities for that state. My format for this is the select id is `WA-cities` for Washington.

Then I wrote this:

```
var detectedCity = data['geoplugin_city'];
var city = detectedCity.replace(" ","-");
var selectedCity = city.toLowerCase();
var stateDash = state + "-";
var selectedValue = stateDash + selectedCity;
$(citySelect).val(selectedValue).attr('selected',true);
```

but when a city that isn't in the select is detected, it just returns the first value. How can I check if that city is in the select and then only select it if it's there. My select is setup like this (for Washington):

```
<select name="cities" id="WA-cities" class="cities">
    <option value="" selected="selected" disabled>Select a City</option>
    <option value="WA-bellingham">Bellingham</option>
    <option value="WA-seattle">Seattle</option>
</select>
```

There are actually more cities in the select. But I'm detected in Mercer Island, which isn't on the select. the JavaScript says `$(citySelect).val('WA-mercer-island).attr('selected',true);` but just chooses the Bellingham one because there's no Mercer Island. What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(citySelect).val(selectedValue).attr('selected',true);
```

This doesn't mean "Set the option which value = selectedValue". It's wrong.

This is the right way,

```
$(citySelect + 'option[value="'+selectedValue+'"]').attr('selected',true);
```

[here is a jsFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/wfAH5/1)